# What is Heroku Procfile for Maven web application on Glassfish?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, heroku, glassfish

I wrote a simple Maven web application on Netbeans. My project works well on localhost on Glassfish server. I tried to upload my project to Heroku but I can not achieve. What is appropriate Procfile for me?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorialspoint_jsf_2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>tutorialspoint_jsf_2</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried this bu it do not work:

```
web:    java -cp target/dependency/*:target/classes com.mycompany.tutorialspoint_jsf_2.jsfYonetimliNesne
```

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 4):

If you want your application running on a Glassfish (on Heroku), you have to use an embedded Glassfish. You know that?

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

As procfile you could then use for example:

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.example.Main
```

In your main you start your glassfish like this:

```
String port = System.getenv("PORT");
GlassFishProperties gfProps = new GlassFishProperties();
gfProps.setPort("http-listener", Integer.parseInt(port));
GlassFish glassfish = GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap().newGlassFish(gfProps);
glassfish.start();          
Deployer deployer = glassfish.getDeployer();            
File file = new File("YourSimpleMavenWebapplication.war");      
deployer.deploy(file);
```

Comment: I added your code to my project but I get these errors:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/embeddable/GlassFishException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)

`

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)`

Comment: You have two separate projects? One to start the glassfish server and to deploy your war file. And the other project for your webapp (that will be deployed)

Comment: No I have only one project. I created it Maven->Web Application on Netbeans.

Comment: Maybe you don't even need glassfish, then you can use one of the demo projects that comes with the heroku eclipse plugin. (There you can choose between Tomcat and Jetty)

Comment: I succeed by using Tomcat. Thanks to this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner. Thank you.